# Java Selenium no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to locate a web element with linkText of "T-shirts". I first located the parent class and then tried to located the element. I printed the tag name of the its parent and it works as expected. But I cannot locate the element using either linkText or partialLinkText. The webpage is http://automationpractice.com/index.php.

```
    WebElement tshirts_tab = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".sf-menu.clearfix.menu-content.sf-js-enabled.sf-arrows"));
    System.out.println(tshirts_tab.getTagName());
    WebElement tshirts = tshirts_tab.findElement(By.partialLinkText("T-shirts"));

    System.out.println(tshirts.getAttribute("href"));
```

[html inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcprK.png)

Comment: Not sure if this helps you, by try looking for nodes using CSS selectors in Chrome and see if your syntax is correct. Think you putting website link in post may have hosed that server! (use inspect - ctrl-f - then type selector). And in the screenshot you gave - li with class and no equals a quoted string looks malformed...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WebElement tshirts = tshirts_tab.findElement(By.partialLinkText("T-SHIRTS"));
```

or

```
WebElement tshirts = tshirts_tab.findElement(By.linkText("T-SHIRTS"));
```

According to the WebDriver spec https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver1/#link-text

"Let **rendered text** be the value that would be returned via a call to Get Element Text for element."

In your case you can see that element you are looking for via linktext has a style `"text-transform: uppercase;"` which in fact transforms the text **render** as upper case.

You can find this element using different locator and then call `.getText()` method and see that it actually returns "T-SHIRTS". So calling for a `linkText` should also be provided with "T-SHIRTS" (rendered text) as a parameter.